# How to exit from stuck full screen application on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, freeze

On Windows 7, pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete and selecting Task manager would almost always hide any full screen apps to the taskbar. In the case it didn't, it at least did put the task bar over the stuck application.

I had a stuck at loading on windows 10, and none of those tricks from Win7 worked. I could get into the Ctrl+Alt+Del menu. I could select Task manager, but the frozen program was still on fullscreen.

I eventually solved the issue by logging out, but that also closed other windows that I'd rather not have closed.

Is there an alternative to what I used to do on Windows 7? Maybe some registry fiddling would make the fullscreen mode more stable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual way to get into and out of full screen mode is by using the
<kbd>F11</kbd> key.

If this does not work for you, try to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
to open the application menu and click (or use the keyboard) to choose
*Restore* or *Minimize*.

Another way is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>
to open the Task Manager. If it is still covered by the always-on-top
full-screen program, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
to open its Options menu and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select *Always on Top*
for the Task Manager.

Answer (score 4):

This is a really common problem for me with games. The game will freeze and lock up the whole pc. I can open apps in the background, but the game is stuck displaying over everything and I can't access anything else because it takes priority visually over everything else. So far, the best solution for me came randomly a while ago. Press Windows Key + Tab and you will have the option to open another desktop instance. You can use this instance to close the frozen program using task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. It closes the application.

Also you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and select `Close`.

Also you can do task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> > `Task manager`).

If task manager does not come up press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Did you read the question? It is about stuck programs that refuse to close and obscure the task manager.\

Comment: "refuse to close" i didnt know that

Comment: yes but  <kbd>alt+o</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> works.

Comment: @someuser no, it doesn't. that assumes that app has system menu and it still processes events

Answer (score -1):

If none of these other suggestions I have gotten a solution that may work. Try to drag the steam app more inward. This problem randomly occurs to people such as myself and a few others whereupon launching the steam app will automatically drag the windows borders to the edges of your screen looking as if you were in full screen mode. The easiest way to tell if this has happened to you is to press the fullscreen button on the top right of your screen. If the window does not look like it has been affected then you may possibly be encountering this bug.